# How to access the pointer array inside the 3 dimentional pointer of struct

Tags: c

I have these structs declared :

```
typedef struct
{
  double* weight;
  char *etiquette;

  double active;
}Neuron;

typedef struct
{
  Neuron **grid;
  Neuron *capteur;
  double alpha;
  int rv;
}SOM;
```

and then somewhere in my program I have a pointer to the second structure

```
SOM *net;
```

then I want to access the *weight variable from net. I can access it with

```
net->capteur->weight;
```

but `net->grid[0][0]->weight` has errors. Then I use `net->grid[0][0].weight` and it compiles but gives me a segmentaion fault.
What is wrong with `net->capteur->weight;` statement and how can I fix it?

Comment: how do you initialize it?

Comment: net=(SOM*)malloc(sizeof(SOM));
net->grid = malloc(sizeof(Neuron*)*N);
for(i = 0;i< M;i++)
  net->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(Neuron)*M);

Comment: @tokafr `for(i = 0;i< M;i++)` should be `for(i = 0;i < N;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

grid and weight are pointer. Have you initialize it?
if you want to read weight value you should do:
*(net->grid[0][0].weight)

Comment: I have a function which returns double* and I want to do:
net->grid[0][0]->weight = functin();

Comment: @tokafr `net->grid[0][0]->weight` won't compile. The correct way would be `net->grid[0][0].weight`